# angularjs using of service and set $scope variable outside of then function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that responsible for creating a grid:

```
    app.directive('gridControl', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            objectType: "=objecttype",
            gridFields: "=gridfields"
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/modules/gridControl.html',
        controller: 'gridControlController'
    };
  });
```

The controller is like below:

```
standardApp.controller('gridControlController', ["$scope", "$stateParams", "gridControlService",
function gridformController($scope, $stateParams, gridControlService) {
    var fields = [];
    gridControlService.getGridStructure($stateParams.id).then(function (result) {
        fields = result.data.Fields;
    });
    $scope.mainGridOptions = fields;
}]);
```

When i want to manipulate $scope.mainGridOptions in my view it is empty! can any one help me to fix it? 
***Note: I want to give fields array to $scope.mainGridOptions outside of then function.**

Comment: it is empty because this line `$scope.mainGridOptions = fields;` gets executed before your services returns a value. Why do you want to populate `$scope.mainGridOptions` outside of then function?

Comment: I know the reason for this problem, but don't know how to fix this. That is what i need sir, If you could just give me a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason** is `gridControlService.getGridStructure($..` something about `asynchronous`. so for that `js` never holds until that `asynchronous` event to be finish instead it will execute the rest of the script. So that `$scope.mainGridOptions = fields;` will execute before the `.then(function (result)` that means, `fields` is just an empty array.

I think `$scope.mainGridOptions = fields;` is not necessary, you have a better way to achieve this. give a try as below

```
gridControlService.getGridStructure($stateParams.id).then(function (result)       
{
    $scope.mainGridOptions = result.data.Fields;
});
// and remove the line $scope.mainGridOptions = fields;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but as I said before i want to set $scope.mainGridOptions in that way.
Is it possible or not?

Comment: yea of cause you can remove `var fields = [];` and add `$scope.mainGridOptions = [];`